# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, classcastexception

Whenever I am trying to get the errorCode from the exception received from `task.getException()` by typecasting to "FirebaseAuthException" it gives and error as `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException` and it always returns
"An Error has occurred [INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS]" by the getMessage method
`task.getException().getMessage();`

Here is the code which is causing the error.

`String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();`

I have provided invalid credentials just to get the exception, but I am not getting the exact exception like if the password is wrong the email is incorrect, or user is not found, etc.

I am using Android Studio Giraffe, 2022.3.1 Patch 2

Here are the dependencies I am using

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.2")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.2.1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using the following line of code:

```
String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();
```

The type of object that is returned by `task.getException()` is [FirebaseException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseException). Trying to cast such an object to an object of type 
[FirebaseAuthException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException) will indeed produce the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException

Why? Because you cannot cast an object of a super-class into an object of a sub-class. Please note that the inheritance relationship is FirebaseAuthException extends FirebaseException and not vice versa. Where the FirebaseException class is the super-class, while the FirebaseAuthException is the sub-class.

Please also note that a FirebaseAuthException is thrown only if signing in via the [startActivityForSignInWithProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#public-taskauthresult-startactivityforsigninwithprovider-activity-activity,-federatedauthprovider-federatedauthprovider) method has been disabled in the Firebase Console, or if the provider passed is configured improperly.

If you want to get more details about the Exception, then you should consider calling [getCause()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable#getCause()), [getMessage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable#getMessage()), or [printStackTrace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable#printStackTrace()).

**Edit:**

When it comes to errors like this:

> INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS

Then please also see the answer below:

- [I Don't get Error codes of Firebase Auth in my Flutter App (I ONLY get INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249904/i-dont-get-error-codes-of-firebase-auth-in-my-flutter-app-i-only-get-invalid-l/77250121#77250121)

Comment: But the `task.getException().getMessage()` method should return the exact exception but it is always returning "An Error has occured [INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS]" in every exception. Just by this statement how can I get the cause of exception.

Comment: In my previous projects, the same code was working fine and I was able to cast.

Comment: Then that's the problem, `INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS`. That's the cause, you have used invalid credentials. There is no way you can perform such a cast.

Comment: Please also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77250121/5246885).

Comment: Yes, your comment helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the comment in the answer. Is it OK now? Can I help you with other information?